# Why the pmatrix environment get a higher parenthese than pmatrix command?

Tags: amsmath

I found the `amsmath` package's `pmatrix` environment have a bit difference with LaTeX's `pmatrix` command. You can see it from:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
\linespread{1.3}
\begin{document}
$\pmatrix{A&B\cr C&D\cr}$
% $\begin{pmatrix}A&B\cr C&D\cr\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

and:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\linespread{1.3}
\begin{document}
% $\pmatrix{A&B\cr C&D\cr}$
$\begin{pmatrix}A&B\cr C&D\cr\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

Is this a feature of `amsmath`?

Comment: What version of amsmath are you using?  Your first example gives me an error `old form \pmatrix should be \begin{pmatrix}...`  So it looks like you are using a deprecated and no longer supported syntax.

Comment: @Matthew: But the first example doesn't use amsmath.

Comment: it is a feature of amsmath, it has some more environments for matrices, e.g. `bmatrix`

Comment: Other than noting that the two are implemented quite differently, I don't think it's easy to give a useful answer to this question. But I do find the extra vertical space taken by the amsmath array constructs to be (slightly) annoying.

Comment: @Harald: Ah, I get it now.  Sorry to be thick.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be due to the `\linespread{1.3}`. I'm not sure if this is a feature of `amsmath` or a bug. Depends on your point of view, I suppose. Feel like a bug. Especially if you use an absurd `\linespread` factor (e.g., 5).

Comment: even so, there is few people concern...

Comment: @Rushavski: I don't know what you mean. Are you saying that only a few people care about the bug? It could be that the AMS doesn't know about the bug or they think it is a bug. It might be best to file a bug report with them. I don't have the URL handy, but I know it has been mentioned on tex.SX before, for what that's worth.

Comment: sorry for my rude behavior. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @Rushavski: Nothing seemed rude, I just didn't understand is all.

Answer (score 0):

I never use `\linespread`, and if you look at the very fine document `mathmode.pdf` I think it will be difficult to find how to use `\linespread`. If you make some investigations on the web, you can find `\linespread{1.3} \selectfont`. I think if you really need to get some space, `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}` is a better idea!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 

\linespread{1.3}% do nothing !!! without \selectfont   

$\begin{pmatrix}A&B\cr C&D\cr\end{pmatrix}$  

\linespread{1.3} \selectfont 

$\begin{pmatrix}A&B\cr C&D\cr\end{pmatrix}$  

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
$\begin{pmatrix}A&B\cr C&D\cr\end{pmatrix}$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't understand me. The `\linespread` command is not use to stretch the array, but to get suitable text (it's omitted by me) line spacing. And, I put the `\linespread` command before the `\begin{document}` to get a globally setting, that don't need followed by `\selectfont`.